# How to get LinkedIn user updates in android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am integrating LinkedIn in my application I have access-token now I want to fetch all the updates feeds of the authenticated user but can't be able to figure it out. I am using Linked-in-J Library please help me to solve this below is the code which I am using to authenticating and getting the name of user. Thanks...

```
private void linkedInLogin() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                LinkedInSampleActivity.this);// .show(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
        // null, "Loadong...");

        LinkedinDialog d = new LinkedinDialog(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                progressDialog);
        d.show();

        // set call back listener to get oauth_verifier value
        d.setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVerify(String verifier) {
                try {
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "verifier: " + verifier);

                    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService
                            .getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken,
                                    verifier);
                    LinkedInApiClient client = LinkedinDialog.factory
                            .createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

                    Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
                    // Person pn=(Person) client.getUserUpdates();

                    System.out.println("My Status= " + p.getCurrentShare());

                    System.out.println("Get Updates= " + p.getFirstName());

                    // p.getCurrentShare()

                    CredentialStore credentialStore = new SharedPreferencesCredentialStore(
                            linkedInpref);
                    credentialStore.write(new String[] {
                            accessToken.getToken(),
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret() });

                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "ln_access_token: "
                            + accessToken.getToken());
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "ln_Token Secret_token: "
                            + accessToken.getTokenSecret());

                } catch (LinkedInOAuthServiceException e) {
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "error to get verifier");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // set progress dialog
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
     p.getCurrentStatus();
```

Here you have to get the profile of current user like this:

```
     Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID));
```